# Rails - how to add timestamps to a model?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I have an exist model (and table) with these columns: `id`, `name`, `city`. In this table are data and I would like to this table add the columns `created_at` and `updated_at` - could anyone give me a help, how to do it? I mean - if I create a model, so these two columns are created automatically and the time informations are inserted always automatically, when I save there something.

Is possible now to add these two columns with automatic inserting time-data?

Comment: So you have an existing model that you would like to add timestamps to? What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: The rails activerecord automatically creates timestamp columns, why you want to add your timestamp columns?

Comment: @megas, he may have removed them from his initial migration

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should allow you to add timestamp columns to an already existing model

```
rails generate migration add_timestamps_to_users
```

This will create a migration file for you. Open it up and make necessary changes

```
class AddTimestampsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  # in my example i'm using `users` table; change this to match your table name
  def change_table :users do |t|
    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

Then migrate your database

```
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Good answer, its also good to note that you want to modify the commands to match the name of the model that you are modifying.

Comment: This solution is not applicable to table containing data, because newly created columns should have default values and "timestamps" syntax does not allow to specify them.

Comment: Paul, how do you expect to make up the date/time values for pre-existing records? I think `null` values are sufficient for records that were created before the timestamp column existed.

Answer (score 14):

It should be noted that while maček's answer is right at the core, he doesn't use the correct syntax for migrations (forgot the "change" method).

So here is his answer with corrected syntax:

This should allow you to add timestamp columns to an already existing model

```
rake generate migration add_timestamps_to_users
```

This will create a migration file for you. Open it up and make necessary changes

```
class AddTimestampsToModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
  # in my example i'm using `users` table; change this to match your table name
  def change
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Then migrate your database

```
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 12):

[`add_timestamps`](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.1.0/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_timestamps) is a dedicated method for this purpose:

```
class AddTimestampsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_timestamps :users
  end
end
```